# F# interactive development

Tags: f#

Coming from a Matlab and R background where the development process is very interactive (select, run selection, fix, select, run selection, fix, etc), I'm trying to figure out how F# handles this style of development, which seems pretty important in scientific applications.  Here are few things that just immediately come to mind to somebody new to F#:

1. Selecting multiple lines gives different results than one line at a time.

   ```
   let add x y = x + y
   add 4.1 2.3
   ```

   Selecting both lines results in `float -> float -> float` whereas selecting the first line results in `int -> int -> int`.  More generally, matlab/R users are used to results printing out after each statement, not at the end.
2. Shadow copying can become burdensome.

   ```
   let file = open2GBfile('file.txt')
   process file
   ```

   If you run this interactively over and over again, the 2GB file is shadow copied and you will quickly run out of memory.  Making file mutable doesn't seem like the appropriate solution, since the final run of the program will never change it.

Given these issues, is it impossible for a `fsi.exe` based system to support matlab/R style interactive development?

[Edit: I am guessing about 2. Do objects get marked for deletion as soon as they are shadowed?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect F# to be a drop-in replacement for Matlab/R, because unlike them, F# is a general purpose programming language.  Not everything you need for a specific type of work will be in the standard libraries.  But that doesn't mean that the "interactive development" you describe is impossible, it may just require some effort up-front to build the library functions you depend on.

For #1, as was mentioned earlier, adding type annotations is unfortunately necessary in some cases, but also the `inline` keyword and "hat-types" can [give you duck-typing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2009/06/11/f-duck-typing-and-structural-typing.aspx).

For #2, I'm not clear on what your `open` and `process` functions do, versus what you want them to do.  For example, the `open` function could:

- Read the entire file at once, return the data as an array/list/etc, and then close the file
- Return a `FileStream` object, which you're calling `process` on but forget to close.
- Return a sequence expression so you can lazily iterate over the file contents
- [Memoize](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx) the result of one of the above, so that subsequent calls just return the cached result
- One of the gazillion other ways to create an abstraction over file access.

Some of these are better suited for your task than others.  Compared to Matlab & R, a general purpose language like F# gives you more ways to shoot yourself in the foot.  But that's because it gives you more ways to do everything.

Comment: I meant open in the Matlab/R style.  It opens a csv file, say, and puts it into a big array/matrix.  My worry is that if I then select and run that code again, which happens in an interactive development style, I'll have two big matrices, one that is shadowed copied.  Am I correct?

Comment: @Tristan: The .Net garbage collection should get rid of the extra "shadow copies" as you refer to them.  The original post sounded like you had tried this and it was a problem.  Now, it sounds like you are just guessing that this will be a problem.  Could you clear that up?

Comment: @John: Yes I am guessing.  I am trying to figure out whether ``let = x 1;; let x = 2;;`` is the same as `x' going out of scope.  Does x = 1 object get marked for deletion as soon as I do ``let x = 2``?  Chris Smith's book refers to this as shadowing.

Comment: I just tried a simple experiment in fsi.exe, allocating (non-zero) arrays while watching memory usage, and Tristan seems to be correct that without using `mutable` or ref-cells, the memory never gets freed.  But then again, writing the extra `mutable` or `ref` in your let declaration, and then using `<-` or `:=` on later assignments doesn't seem like too much of an annoyance, IMHO.

Comment: @Gabiel: If you actually are changing x it's true that making it mutable would be the right strategy.  However here I have in mind running the same code many times in fsi as you debug it.  That's what typically happens in matlab style development.  If your objects are small this won't matter so much. However if you load a big matrix five times things could quickly get ugly.  It doesn't make sense to use ``mutable`` because in the actual code you never mutate it.

Comment: @Tristan: Yes, that makes sense, but of course when you say "actual code", that distinction is not something that fsi.exe understands.  Short of modifying fsi so that it doesn't retain references to "shadowed" objects (the source is provided), it seems your best bet might be to restart fsi occasionally, and maintain source files with "startup" code to run on each restart.  I find myself doing that when playing with non-trivial things in fsi.  This tends to lead to clean, modular code and makes it easier to document what you've done (and what works), so you can retrace your steps later.  HTH.

Comment: @Gabriel:  That sounds like a reasonable approach although it isn't like matlab.  Is there a reason shadow copies are kept around?  For instance; let x = 1; let a = x; let x = 2?  What happens if I delete the first shadowed x?

Comment: I'm not on the "inside" of F#, I'm just a semi-regular user, so I have no idea why fsi works this way--maybe it was just easier to program this way (remember F# is a new language, and an even newer product--there are still kinks to be worked out).  In any case, as far as I can tell, the shadowing occurs because each `let` declaration makes a new static field on an in-memory CLR type.  So I don't think it is possible to "delete" x.  If x were a reference type and you declared it were mutable (or a ref-cell of a value type), then you could set it to null.  But we already discussed that :)

Answer (score 1):

To #1

In FSI, you'll have to type `;;` at the end of each statement and get the results directly:

```
> 1 + 2;;
val it : int = 3
```

Generally an F#-Codefile should be seen as a collection of individual functions that you have to call and evaluate interactively and not as a series of steps that produce values to be shown.

To #2:

This seems to be a problem of the code itself: Make `file` a function, so the reading/copying is only done when and where really needed (otherwise the let binding would be evaluated in the beginning).

Comment: The issue is that this changes the type inferences.

Comment: Then annontate the types explicitly where it can't be avoided.

Comment: Note that this is a fault of F#'s type system. In interactive Haskell (GHCi), it's much better because the type system can generalize such functions using typeclasses.